# how to working in tree view child node click event in c#

Tags: c#

i am working in treeview in which no option for the child node and parent node click event so plz suggest me to work on Both click event

my code is

```
  private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        if (treeView1.SelectedNode = "Edit User")
        {
            label2.Visible = true;

        }
        else
        {
            label2.Visible = false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I am sorry, I have read this question over and over and I really don't know what you are asking, could you be more clear about what you want to happen?

Comment: NodeMouseClick event could help

Comment: Btw, you should avoid putting "C#" in your question title, you already have it as a tag

Answer (score 2):

Try This :

```
private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Node.Text = "Edit User")
        {
            label2.Visible = true;

        }
        else
        {
            label2.Visible = false;
        }

    }
```